# Как изменить БД через DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

Хочу изменять значения в таблице DataGrid так, чтобы они сразу же сохранялись в БД. Я нашел события Row(Cell)EditEnding,но дальше не знаю, что делать. Как взять все строки DataGrid и заменить ими строки БД?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVVM: https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/162581/

В данном случае:

```
private void dataGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    Person p = e.Row.Item as Person;
    dbContext.Persons.AddOrUpdate(p);
}
```

Вроде, должно работать. Главное - забиндить ItemsSource DataGrid'a к контексту нужной таблицы БД.

Comment: теперь понял, спасибо